# Aggregating on a ReferenceField in Mongoengine

Tags: python, aggregation, mongoengine

In my app, I have a model for tracking site activity:

```
class FeedItem(Document):
    user = ReferenceField('User')
    link = ReferenceField('Link')
    issue = ReferenceField('Threat')
    action = StringField(required=True, max_length=1000)
    datetime = DateTimeField(required=True)
```

... where I keep track of what users do to content.

I am trying to create a "top users" list, where I aggregate a list of users by those who have made the most contributions (as determined, at least initially, by the number of times they show up in the log).

I tried this:

```
user_freqs = FeedItem.objects.item_frequencies('user', normalize=True)
top_users = sorted(user_freqs.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:10]
```

(based on [this example](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#further-aggregation))

But I realized that that doesn't work because item_frequencies() doesn't work on ReferenceFields.

I am new at this, and am at a bit of a loss.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using raw pymongo and the aggregation framework, its a simple group by on `FeedItem.user` and `$sum`.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm having a hard time figuring out the syntax for passing aggregate() using the __raw__ keyword -- from the docs, I can see how to do it for more simple queries.

Here's what I have, which is wrong:

`top_users = User.objects(__raw__=aggregate({....`

Clearly I'm not understanding how that should work (this is my first time w all of this).

Thx again for your help.

Comment: Oh, I think you actually mean "raw pymongo", not the __raw__ keyword.  will try that.